# KerasRegressor in sklearn Pipeline with OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to build full sklearn Pipeline where at the end is Keras model within wrapper KerasRegressor.

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("numerical", num_pipeline, num_columns),
        ("categorical", cat_pipeline, cat_columns)
    ],
    n_jobs=-1
)

# final pipeline for entire process
pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocessing", preprocessor),
        ("model", None)
    ])
```

Next, model is updated by pipe.set_params().

```
param = {"model": KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model, epochs=100)}

pipe.set_params(**param)
```

Function build_model looks like this:

```
def build_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(20, input_dim=..., activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
    return model
```

Problem is, that first layer in Sequential model requires input_dim attribute, which is unknown at the beginning (cannot be hardcoded).

One step of Pipeline is OneHotEncoder which changes shape of X data.

Even if I would hardcode shape of X in any way, it still does not work in cross_val_score, where those shapes will be different each time depending how many unique values of each categorical features will get there.

Any idea how to solve that? Is there any way to pass to KerasRegressor information about shape of data from previous step of Pipeline?

Comment: if u don't specify input_dim in your sequential model?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it hard to admit, but it works... it's just so easy that I didn't even try this! THANKS